No puedo acceder a mi openproject desde otra PC en mi red local
Instale un OpenProject en un ubuntu que esta dentro de un proxmox, desde el mismo ubuntu puedo acceder al openproject con su ip privada o localhost, el problema viene cuando quiero acceder desde otra pc que esta en la misma red, si coloco la ip privada del ubuntu no me deja, si le fuerzo el http, tampoco me deja, si uso el puerto 3000, tampoco me deja

¿Tienes un firewall ejecutándose en tu sistema Ubuntu?

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

desconozco pero habilite con sudo ufw allow 80 y sudo ufw allow 443

¿Puedes mostrar la configuración IP de ambas computadoras? Incluyendo la subred.  ¿Puedes hacer ping a ambas computadoras?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
